# Padlock does'nt show?

Tags: magento-1.9

When I load my secure login page https://www.9gem.com/,my padlock does'nt show.
[image]

[image]

Comment: some Css files are still loading over http. you need to change all url to https.

Answer (score 0):

it's because some of the content is not over HTTPS.
If you take a look at row three of your first screenshot you'll see that one stylesheet is the issue.

Can you change its URL to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is mixed content in webpage.That is http content on https webpage.

As per the screenshot shared, the google font api link is linked in your page(may be hardcoded) with **http**. Changing it to **https** will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your secure and unsecure Base URL must using https://
Recently I have faced the same problem and solved by adding https to Base URL

```
Admin Path: System->Config->Web
```

[image]